# Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{n!}=0$ without the Sandwich Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> So I want to find: 
>   $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n!}$$

The solution I came up with includes the use of the Sandwich Theorem. So:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb R,\quad|\sin(nx)|\leq 1\quad\Rightarrow\quad -\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right| \leq \frac{\sin(nx)}{n!} \leq \left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|$$
However, $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}-\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|=0$$
So using the Sandwich Theorem 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n!}=0$$

> The result is $0$, but is there another way to prove this, e.g. using L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: You can't use L'Hopital's Rule since you can't differentiate $n!$ with respect to $n$ - it is not continuous.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: Anyway, L'Hospital's rule should generally be avoided.

Comment: Why should it be avoided? If you can explain of course, thanks for your time!

Comment: You can use the theorem on the product of infinitesimal to bounded

Comment: There is no reason why 'L'Hospital' should be avoided. L'Hospital itself is not written to be used with sequences (discrete functions), but there is a [discrete version of L'Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) which is applicable in this case. However, the resulting limit is pretty similar to the one you are computing. So, it doesn't really save much work. You can compute it that way, if you really want.

Comment: For given non-zero $x$, $\frac{\sin{nx}}{nx}\cdot \frac{x}{(n-1)!}$. Limit for both functions exists and are zero. For $x=0$ its trivial.

Comment: Also, note that in this form this is barely the Sandwich theorem; it is clear that if you can bound this above by something going to $0$ then the original sequence goes to $0$ too

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the definition of the limit. Write
$$ \left|\frac{\sin\left(nx\right)}{n!}\right| \leq \frac{1}{n}. $$
Then, given $\epsilon>0$, for any $n > N := \left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right]$ we have $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$ and therefore
$$ \left|\frac{\sin\left(nx\right)}{n!} - 0\right| < \epsilon. $$

Answer (score 0):

We **claim** that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} = 0$.  If we prove this, then we get
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n!} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right)
=\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right)= 0 \cdot 0 = 0 .
$$

Proof of claim.  (to be continued --- I have to avoid sandwitch for this part too --- will require some thought)

Comment: It's going to be difficult to avoid using bounds on $\sin(nx)$ (or maybe $\cos(nx)$) somewhere.  Note that if $x$ is not real, the limit does not exist.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n!}=0$$$$⇔$$$$∀ε>0,∃N∈ℕ^+, ∀n∈ℕ^+(n>N⇒\left|\frac{\sin\left(nx\right)}{n!}\right|<ε)$$

$$n>N⇒\left|\frac{\sin\left(nx\right)}{n!}\right|<\frac{\left|nx\right|}{n!}=\frac{\left|x\right|}{\left(n-1\right)!}\le\frac{\left|x\right|}{2^{\left(n-2\right)}}<ε$$

$$n>N⇒2^{\left(n-2\right)}>\frac{\left|x\right|}{ε}$$

Since $\log_{a}\left(x\right)$ is increasing over its domain for $a>1$, so we have:

$$n>N⇒n>\log_{2}\left(\frac{\left|x\right|}{ε}\right)+2$$

Hence take $N\ge\log_{2}\left(\frac{\left|x\right|}{ε}\right)+2$ and the result follows.

Another way would be using Stirling approximation.